# Returning next element of array onClick

Tags: android

This is my code:

```
final ArrayList<Integer> number1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i <= 13; ++i)
        number1.add(i);
    Collections.shuffle(number1);

attack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final ImageView img = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.randomOp);
            int i = 0;
            final String str = "img" + number1.get(i);
            if (i == 13){
                Collections.shuffle(number1);
            }
            i++;
            img.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(getResourceID(str, "drawable", getContext())));
        }
    });
```

What I want to do is every time the onClick event occurs it would return the next element of the array. The above code is obviously wrong as it creates int i and assigns it value 0, and it does that every time I press the button. So I suppose I should put it in the main method, but it has to be final then and I can't change it's value every time the button is pressed. How could I make it so the integer wouldn't be reseted every time I press the button?

Comment: do you only need numbers 1-12 to be returned or is this only an examle?

Comment: Yes I need only those numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare your `int i` as a field variable of your class/activity. It need not be final then. And reset its value to zero when it reaches 13.

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity {

    private int i = 0;

    //rest of your code ....

}
```

You code should look like this,

```
final ArrayList<Integer> number1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i <= 13; ++i)
        number1.add(i);
    Collections.shuffle(number1);

attack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final ImageView img = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.randomOp);                
            final String str = "img" + number1.get(i);
            i++;
            if (i == 13){
                Collections.shuffle(number1);
                i = 0;
            }                
            img.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(getResourceID(str, "drawable", getContext())));
        }
    });
```